# redshift to_timestamp() without millisecond

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

how to convert string `2017-06-20T09:52:33+0000` to timestamp `2017-06-20 09:52:33`. I tried this but I still got the last `+00`:

```
select to_timestamp(substring('2017-06-20T09:52:33+0000',1,19), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  

>> 2017-06-20 09:52:33+00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select left(to_timestamp(substring('2017-06-20T09:52:33+0000',1,19), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),19);

>> 2017-06-20 09:52:33
```

This'll work for sure. Do let me know if you still face issues.